# Strategies on obtaining the Dizzy Yet achievement

Tags: achievements, turbo-dismount

In Turbo Dismount, the description for the *Dizzy Yet?* achievement reads:

> Pull ten somersaults in a single dismount.

I have not been able to figure out how to do so. Are there any strategies for obtaining this achievement, such as a certain level and obstacle setup to use?

Answer (score 1):

I found two possible strategies :

- on Froggerer, try to get bounced by the NPC vehicles without getting ripped apart <sup>[link](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=262966055&insideModal=1)</sup>
- using [Blackjack's Bus Serpentine](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=270252922&searchtext=bus+serpentine) from the Workshop <sup>[link](http://steamcommunity.com/app/263760/discussions/0/522728269407048615/)</sup>

[image: Bus Serpentine screenshot]